# how to fast save the image capture from camera to album

Tags: avfoundation, capture

I am using AVFoundation to implement captureStillImage function.

When I use the follow  code to write an Image to album on iphone ,

```
if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {

    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"capturestill image size is %@", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage]
        orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation]
        completionBlock:completionBlock];
    [image release];

    [library release];
}
```

it throw an error like this:

Write Busy, 
There was a problem writing  this asset because the writing resources are busy.

Any one can point out where is the problem?

Comment: Did you below answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the error in the completion block and if it is ALAssetsLibraryWriteBusyError, then you need to try to save that asset again. It means something else was trying to write to disk when the method attempted to write to disk.